# U does not fade away more weakly than $\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^{n-2}}$

Tags: analysis

Hello I have a function $u$ and it is said that for $n>2$ it does not fade away (in German: abklingen) more weakly than $\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^{n-2}}$.

What is meant with that?

I do not know this manner of speaking...

Answer (score 0):

This might mean that $$\lim_{\| x\| \to \infty} \frac{u(x)}{\|x\|^{n-2}} < \infty .$$

Comment: What would that mean for the expression $\frac{\lVert x\rVert^{n-2}}{R^{n-2}}u(x), \lVert x\rVert >R$?

Comment: It might mean that.  It's difficult to parse because of the implicit double negative combining "does not fade away" and "more weakly than".  Perhaps the best approach would be (if one knows the context) to ask what "u fading away more weakly than $||x||^{-n+2}$" would entail.

Comment: I'll give you the context in a new question, ok?

Comment: The interested reader should see [this Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600135/show-that-the-kelvin-transform-is-bounded).